# Flattening an array in PHP

Tags: php

I have gone through a selection of posts here on how to flatten a PHP array, but none of them have helped me to work out how to get the array down to the level I want.

The array is currently outputting like this:

```
array(4) { [0]=> array(1) { ["entry_id"]=> string(3) "342" } [1]=> array(1) { ["entry_id"]=> string(3) "343" } [2]=> array(1) { ["entry_id"]=> string(3) "344" } [3]=> array(1) { ["entry_id"]=> string(3) "345" } }
```

I would like to have it like so:

```
array = (342,343,344,345)
```

I have managed to get it down to this:

```
array(4) { [0]=> string(3) "342" [1]=> string(3) "343" [2]=> string(3) "344" [3]=> string(3) "345" }
```

With this code:

```
foreach($submissions as $a=>$b) {
            $submissions[$a] = $b['entry_id'];
        }
```

Thank you.

Comment: I think the issue you are trying to solve is the presence of the `string(3)` right? In which case in your loop do `intval($b['entry_id'])`

Comment: If you're using PHP 5.5, then [array_column()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) might prove a useful function

Comment: @ZackNewsham Thanks. That has gotten down to : array(4) { [0]=> int(342) [1]=> int(343) [2]=> int(344) [3]=> int(345) }
I really want to remove the keys as well, and just have the values with commas between. Is this possible?

Comment: How are you actually outputting this array though: var_dump() or print_r() are for debugging purposes rather than user display; use echo or print for displaying values for users

Comment: I think arrays in PHP always have keys - otherwise they wouldnt be an array, right?

Comment: Okay, I guess I want to create a string from my array. But how do I get rid of the keys?

Comment: You __don't__ get rid of the keys unless you cast an array entry to a string, you just don't display them

Comment: `implode(",", $submissions);`

Comment: Thank you Zack. That did the job!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like

```
foreach($submissions as $a=>$b) {
            $submissions[] = $b['entry_id'];
        }
```

Because you're giving the array key=>val and the way i understand your request is you just want the values?